# bootstrap selectpicker and cloning

Tags: bootstrap-select

I have been using bootstrap selectpicker where I've added an Add Button for user to replicate the button as much as he wants. Problem is, selectpicker is not working on the second / cloned element and values of dropdown are just showing and not changing on click.

Main Select:

```
<div id="main_product">
  <select name="product[]" class="selectpicker" >
   <option value="Tube Lights" >Tube Lights</option>
   <option value="Downlights" >Downlights</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Clone Function:

```
function clone()
{
    var $orginal = $('#main_product');
    var $cloned = $orginal.clone();

    $cloned.appendTo('#new_products');
    // $cloned.find('.bootstrap-select').remove();
    // $cloned.find('select').selectpicker();
}
```

Note that I tried to reassign the selectpicker to the cloned object which is in comments atm, because it dint work also.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I came across this problem but if using the latest version now the select is placed inside the .bootstrap-select element for html5 error handling purposes. The remove() also removes the select, a work around is:

Instead of:

```
$cloned.find('.bootstrap-select').remove();
```

Use:

```
$cloned.find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); });
```

This will replace the .bootstrap-select element with the select element that it contains inside.

Answer (score 4):

```
function clone()    
{    
  //you can use :    
     var $orginal = $('#main_product');    
     var $cloned = $orginal.clone();    
  //Or    
     var $cloned = $('#main_product').clone(); 

  //then use this to solve duplication problem    
     $cloned.find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); })    
     $cloned .find('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render'); 

  //Then Append    
     $cloned.appendTo('#new_products');    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using in **Form Sets** along with other form fields you need to **replace** and **render** all the selectpicker mentioned by @cm_mehdi. First find the new form html element and apply the below code:

```
//Clone new form
let newForm = purchaseForm[0].cloneNode(true);

// Replace and render the cloned html selectpicker

 $(newForm).find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); })
 $(newForm).find('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');

// Re-Initialize search in dropdown
 $(`#id_form_formfield-${formNum}`).selectpicker({liveSearch: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

if we replace the bootstrap-select with the select then the problem is in HTML structure.
so, original element is actual bootstrap-select and cloned are normal select.
take look at following for more clarification.
[image]

instead of this

```
$cloned.find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); });
```

use

```
$cloned.selectpicker('refresh');
$cloned.find('.bootstrap-select:odd').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can please change clone function**

```
function clone() {
    var $orginal = $('#main_product');
    var $cloned = $orginal.clone();
    var $selectPicker = $cloned.find('select');

    $cloned
        .find('.bootstrap-select').remove().end()
        .append($selectPicker).end();
    
    $cloned.find('select').selectpicker();

    $cloned.appendTo('#new_products');
}
```